# Decomposition of the skeleton muscle by alcohol

Tags: muscle, bodybuilding, gym, alcohol

I know that alcohol could suppress the testosterone, which is necessary for the construction of skeleton muscle, in human body; therefore, taking alcohol could slow down the growth of skeleton muscle.

One the other hand, I heard that alcohol could also result in the decomposition of the skeleton muscle. Is it really true?

If so, what is the mechanism behind it?

Would anyone please give me some explanations for it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I could find, like you said, muscle growth can be affected by alcohol as it can reduce muscle protein synthesis by up to 24% if a large amount is consumed. But, I couldn't find any evidence that alcohol consumption actively decomposes muscle, just that it hinders muscle growth and can therefore speed up natural loss of muscle mass that comes with age.

*edit:

[This study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3922864/) does conclude that even when consumed with a sufficient amount of protein, alcohol consumed after exercise does affect the rate of MPS. Unfortunately, the study does not experiment with various doses of alcohol and so I can't for certain say the difference in effect between a large and small amount of alcohol. Logically though, one can assume a relatively low dose, would have a negligible effect.*

Comment: My understanding if the research (don’t have a cite atm) is that low intakes of alcohol get metabolized by the liver before it even has a chance to mess with MPS.

Comment: @Ethan Thank you for the answer. In other words, alcohol does not result in the decomposition of skeleton muscle directly, does it?

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Answer edited with a source. And yes, it is my understanding of the evidence that alcohol only affects muscle protein synthesis, and therfore the building of new muscle, not existing muscle mass.